# How do i get information from my app config in my app script?

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

```
{# @var services \Shopware\Core\Framework\Script\ServiceStubs #}
{% set myInt = services.config.app('myInt') %}
```

I thought this is the way to got, [according to the documentation](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts#available-services), but i do not get the result, its always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tested this with the current stable release and it works as expected.

```
{% do debug.dump(services.config.app('example')) %}
```

Shows the value of `MyAppTechnicalName.config.example` in the scripts section of the profiler.

The system config facade of the service stubs will always take the current sales channel id to get the config values. That means, if you haven't provided a value for all sales channels, but a value for one sales channel and not the other, then you might get no value depending on the sales channel context you're in.

Verify that the value is stored correctly in the table `system_config` with the `configuration_key` being of the pattern `MyAppTechnicalName.config.example` and `sales_channel_id` being `null`, indicating a fallback value for all sales channels.

Answer (score 0):

{{ config('TestApp.config.testVar') }}

TestApp is the name of the App, the root folder of it. testVar is a var you configured in config.xml (Resources/config):

```
<input-field type="text">
    <name>testVar</name>
    <label>Enter some info</label>
</input-field>
```

Comment: That's syntax to be used in templates, not [app scripts](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts).

Comment: Thats right for twig use only, I thought maybe there is a misunderstanding on his side.

Comment: Execution of script "cart/my-script.twig" for Hook "cart" failed with message: Unknown "config" function in cart/my.twig

thats the error i get with your code, won't work there in the app script

Comment: I think you need to provide more background info. App root name, config.xml content, my-script.twig content. Maybe also a screenshot of the project tree, where I can see the files.